# How to skip missing data and continue running loop through rest of data

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements, nested-loops

I'm trying to create a function that can pull the first instance of 1 from Expert_Grading_Score column based off of conditions from other columns (subject and treatment). I created two lists with all unique values from subjects and treatment columns:

```
subj_list = df_sorted['subj'].unique().tolist()
print(subj_list)
```

Output:
[1001, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010, 1011, 1012, 1013, 1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019, 1020, 1021, 1022]

```
Treatment_list = df_sorted['Treatment'].unique().tolist()
print(Treatment_list)
```

Output:
['MPPDDu', 'Product A', 'Product C', 'Product D', 'Product E', 'Product F', 'Product G', 'Product H', 'Std S2', 'Product B', 'Product I', 'Product J']

Then I created a nested for loop to sort through each product on subject basis and apply iloc:

```
score = 1 
for idx, subject in enumerate(subj_list):
    for idx2, treatment in enumerate(Treatment_list):
        selected_subsite = df_sorted[(df_sorted.subj == subject) & (df_sorted.Treatment == treatment) & (df_sorted.Expert_Grading_Score == score)].iloc[0]
        print(selected_subsite)
```

At this point, I get the ouptut I want but get an index error when I reach Product B for subject 1001. After some thought and checking the master datasheet, I realized that there are certain subjects that are missing certain treatments, in this case Product B for subject 1001. I tried adding a continue statement with conditionals to circumvent the missing data:

```
score = 1 
for idx, subject in enumerate(subj_list):
    for idx2, treatment in enumerate(Treatment_list):
        if treatment != '':
            selected_subsite = df_sorted[(df_sorted.subj == subject) & (df_sorted.Treatment == treatment) & (df_sorted.Expert_Grading_Score == score)].iloc[0]
            print(selected_subsite)
        if treatment == '':
            continue
```

But got the same error. How can I adjust this code so that it skips missing datapoints and continues to run for the rest? Any advice would be much appreciated!

[**Example of input dataframe (left) and output dataframe (right):**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acdkm.png)

Comment: could you provide some (real) input and (final) expected output data (to make your problem reproducable)

Comment: also, i do not think that *any* build-in datatype (and definitely not the `list` class) in Python has an `iloc` method, so you need to be more specific on what you are using.

Comment: I have provided an example of what my input data and expected output data would be, edited above. Okay, I'll look into what you mean about list class and iloc method compatability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `if` statement with a `try/except` block, as shown below:

```py
try:
    selected_subsite = df_sorted[(df_sorted.subj == subject) & (df_sorted.Treatment == treatment) & (df_sorted.Expert_Grading_Score == score)].iloc[0]
    print(selected_subsite)
except IndexError as e:
    continue
```

Your code iterates through a list of unique values from the Treatment column, so treatment will never be empty, and the second condition will never be reached.

With this logic provided above, when there are no rows matching the `treatment` and `subject` variables, it will handle the `IndexError` exception and continue the iteration.

Comment: Yes, thank you! The more I thought about it, I realized it's not an issue of missing data but it's because it's searching for something that is not there and cannot move on. I tried and this worked! Thank you again, I've learned something new today

Answer (score 0):

Rather than testing if the treatment is an empty string (or in addition to that) perhaps you should check if the result of the filter produces any rows.  Maybe something like:

```py
for idx, subject in enumerate(subj_list):
    for idx2, treatment in enumerate(Treatment_list):
        df_selected_subsite = df_sorted[(df_sorted.subj == subject) & (df_sorted.Treatment == treatment) & (df_sorted.Expert_Grading_Score == score)]
        if df_selected_subsite and not df_selected_subsite.empty:
            print(df_selected_subsite.iloc[0])
```

Comment: Thank you and good idea, I like where you're heading with this, but will have to look into it more. I get "ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." at line 4. And I struggle with understanding value errors